Closeness of singleton and empty sets over binary operators
Let $A$ an arbitrary set and $\circ : A^2 \to A$ a binary operator. In general, we say $S \subseteq A$ is closed under $\circ$ iff
$$Im ~ \circ_{\mid S} \subseteq S$$
or equivalently iff $\forall (s_1, s_2) \in S^2: s_1 \circ s_2 \in S$.
How does this definition apply if $|S| = 1$, which entails $|S^2| = 1$? Assuming $s \in S$ is the only element in $S$, is it correct to say that $S$ is closed under $\circ$ only if
$$s \circ s = s$$
What about $S = \emptyset$? In this case, at least in principle, there is no $(s_1, s_2) \in S$ s.t. $s_1 \circ s_2 \notin S$ (i.e. no counterexample), so we could say $S$ is closed.
In short, how do we define the closeness of a set over a binary operator when such set is either empty or has cardinality equal to one?

We don't need to define "closed" separately in these special cases; the general definition applies perfectly to these cases too.  We  just take the definition and see what it says in those special cases. The result is that we can prove your characterizations: $\emptyset$ is always closed; ${s}$ is closed iff $s\circ s=s$.
